# OLE DB Command in SSIS holds Exclusive lock on table indefinitely

Tags: ssis, locking

I'm implementing an upsert operation using SSIS

The general package structure is

```
<Begin transaction>

<read config values>

<Data flow task>

<commit transaction>
```

Data flow task is comprised of

```
<oledb Source>

<Lookup>

<matched output to Update using oledbcommand>

<No Match output to Insert using oledbcommand>
```

The package runs fine the 1st time, when there are only inserts

on the second run, when a set of updates have happened, and then an insert has happened, the Update statement ends up holding an exclusive lock on the destination table, goes to sleep with `AWAITING COMMAND`, while the Insert gets suspended and continues waiting for a lock.

To check the statements in the last para, I used the following commands:

```
select * from master.sys.sysprocesses where blocked<>0 or spid in (select blocked from master.sys.sysprocesses where blocked <>0)
```

Is there a way to fix this locking situation?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but is there a reason you are using an OLE DB Command for your inserts? Related to your question, is there a reason you are explicitly controlling your transactions versus deferring to MSDTC?

Comment: @billinkc I tried the DTC, but it gave me a different error (don't have the exact error now, but it was something like `E_DTC_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER`)

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but why are you using upsert with a select/if exists update/if not insert instead of the marvelous `MERGE` command?

Comment: @DominicGoulet can the merge command be used in SSIS? I was under the impression the implementation is buggy. If its safe, I would certainly prefer going with it

Comment: `MERGE` is very safe to use, and yes it works in SSIS. I used it numerous times in BI/Datawarehouse environments with type 2 dimensions. It's a lot faster than the SCD component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OLEDB Command is known to be problematic. It is executed on one row at a time similar to a cursor. So it is slow, specially if you've large number of records to process. I can't exactly say why there is locking but I guess it's because of other processes trying to access the table at the same time.

It's better to change your data flow task to something like this:

oledb source

lookup

No match output to OLEDB Destination, Add a destination directly, you don't need OLEDB command here to do inserts.

Divert matched records to a staging table in destination database

In the control flow, use an execute sql task and update statements to perform updates: this now performs a set based updated. Faster than the original configuration.

[This article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Integration+Services+%28SSIS%29/62063/) on SQL Server Central walks through the implementation. Be advised it's using 2005, you need to make minor changes to the lookup transform to suite 2008.

Comment: Sive - You're correct. And I'm suggesting to change that to use a set based approach.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are explicitly controlling your transactions, have you set the `RetainSameConnection` property to true? Otherwise, you will have two+ database connections to the same resource and inserting and updating the same table but on different transactions and that would result in the behaviour you are experiencing.

Comment: `RetainSameConnection` is set to true :(  Additionally I don't get why Insert and Update want table locks. Shouldn't Row Locks be good enough?

Comment: [Row locks can escalate to table locks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184286(v=sql.105).aspx)